Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Conversation_latestMessageId_key`
This is my prisma schema
model User {
  id            String          @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?         @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  username       String?  @unique
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
 messages       Message[]
  conversations  ConversationParticipant[]

 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
 
model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?
 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
 
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 
  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}
 
model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String   @db.ObjectId
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
 
model VerificationToken {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  identifier String
  token      String
  expires    DateTime
 
  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
 

model Conversation {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  participants    ConversationParticipant[]
  messages        Message[] @relation("conversationMessages")
  latestMessage   Message?   @relation(name: "latestConversationMessage", fields: [latestMessageId], references: [id], onUpdate: NoAction, onDelete: NoAction)
  latestMessageId String?    @unique  @db.ObjectId
  createdAt       DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime  @updatedAt
}

model ConversationParticipant {
  id              String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  user            User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId          String    @db.ObjectId
  conversation    Conversation @relation(fields: [conversationId], references: [id])
  conversationId  String    @db.ObjectId
  hasSeenLatestMessage Boolean
}

model Message {
  id              String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  conversation    Conversation  @relation(name: "conversationMessages", fields: [conversationId], references: [id])
  conversationId  String        @db.ObjectId
  isLatestIn      Conversation? @relation("latestConversationMessage")
  sender          User          @relation(fields: [senderId], references: [id])
  senderId        String        @db.ObjectId
  body            String
  createdAt       DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime      @updatedAt
}

When I run the below query:
const conversation = await prisma.conversation.create({
  data: {
    participants: {
      createMany: {
        data: participantIds.map((id) => ({
          userId: id,
          hasSeenLatestMessage: id === userId,
        })),
      },
    },
  },
  include: {
    participants: {
      include: {
        user: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            username: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    latestMessage: {
      include: {
        sender: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            username: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

The conversation in created in the mongoDB database when there are 0 entries in conversation model. When I again run the same query with different array of participantIDs it throws this error:
CREATE_CONVERSATION_ERROR:  PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.conversation.create()` invocation in
D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\src\graphql\resolvers\conversation.ts:22:56

  19 } = session;
  20 
  21 try {
→ 22   const conversation = await prisma.conversation.create(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Conversation_latestMessageId_key`
    at In.handleRequestError (D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6877)
    at In.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6211)
    at In.request (D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:5919)
    at async l (D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:127:11167)
    at async Object.createConversation (D:\Practice projects\messager\backend\src\graphql\resolvers\conversation.ts:22:30) {
  code: 'P2002',
  clientVersion: '5.15.0',
  meta: {
    modelName: 'Conversation',
    target: 'Conversation_latestMessageId_key'
  }
}

What am i doing wrong?
The expected result would be:
A conversation being created and related conversationParticipants.

Do you have any duplicates for latestMessageId  in conversation collection on mongo?
